# Cast from 'NSManagedObject' to unrelated type always fails

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, preload

I'm trying to load data and save it into the database but I get a warning and an error in `func preloadData()`:

> Cast from 'NSManagedObject' to unrelated type 'LeadItem' always fails

And in `func removData()`:

> cannot convert value of type 'LeadItem' to expected argument type 'NSManagedObject'

Similar solutions for an older version of Xcode aren't working for me.

```
func preloadData ()
{
    if let contentsOfURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("leads_Data", withExtension: "csv")
    {
        removeData()
        var error:NSError?
        if let leads = parseCSV(contentsOfURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)
        {
            for lead in leads
                {
                    let leadItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("LeadItem", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! LeadItem
                }
        }
    }
}

func removeData ()
{
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "LeadItem")
    do
        {
            let leadItems = try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [LeadItem]
            for leadItem in leadItems
            {
                self.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(leadItem)
            }
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print("Failed to retrieve record: \(error.localizedDescription) \n")

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is LeadItem a subclass of NSManagedObject?  Did you create the model class from an Xcode data model?

Comment: I think it solved my problems, thank you

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: How did you solve the problem?